# Memory Caching for ASP MVC apps running on Mono using Nginx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mono, nginx

I have some https ASP MVC 2 web services that run on linux machines using Mono and Nginx.

How can I configure them work with the [Output Cache](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs) feature of ASP MVC?

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(Duration=10)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
}
```

I want to store the cache on the same machine that that runs the webservice.

I've tried adjusting my nginx configuration to include proxy_cache and redirect to another port on the same machine to run the original request, using much of the code found in this [example](http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2010/01/13/asp-net-performance-part-5-nginx/).  However, I've had no luck getting it to work.

Here's what I have:

```
proxy_cache_path /usr/local/nginx/proxy_temp/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:10m inactive=10m max_size=250M;
proxy_temp_path /usr/local/nginx/proxy_temp/tmp;

server
{
   listen   443 ssl;
   server_name myserver.com;

   ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/ssl/nginx_https.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/ssl/nginx_https.key;


    location /
    {
                    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
                    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:4430;
                    proxy_cache cache;
                    proxy_cache_valid 200 302 60m;
                    proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;

    }
}


server
{
   listen   4430 ssl;

   root          /var/www/mywebpage/;

   ssl_certificate /home/user/ssl/https.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /home/user/ssl/https.key;

    location /
    {
            index index.html index.htm default.aspx Default.aspx;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

If I add the line:

```
proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
```

Then the caching works, however it starts caching everything, I only want it to cache the methods marked with the OutputCache attribute in my MVC app, though I'm not sure how to properly configure the Nginx cache to deal with it.

What is the proper way to couple the Nginx caching system with the Output Cache attributes of an ASP MVC app running on Mono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx caching and ASP.NET caching **are two completely** separate things. If you use `[OutputCache]` in your ASP.NET project, Nginx will not be aware of that. And vice versa, the `proxy_cache_*` directives in your nginx config will in no way affect the ASP.NET caching.

You should decide where to cache, either use nginx or use ASP.NET. If you want to use Nginx for caching, remove the [OutputCache] attribtues or disable output caching via `web.config` alltogether. Instead, create different locations for different cache zones in nginx like this:

```
# for your Home controller, assuming you use the /home/ route
location /home/ {
    proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:4430;
    proxy_cache cache;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m;
    proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
}
# for all other routes
location / {
    proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:4430;
    # no proxy_cache here means no caching on the nginx side
}
```

You can create complex `location` sections and use even regular expression to match your ASP.NET pathes/routes. See the [nginx docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) about that.

If you want to control caching from within ASP.NET, remove any `proxy_cache*` directives from  the nginx configuration (like in the last `location` section in the example above) and use the regular ASP.NET caching directives like `[OutputCache]` directive.

I'd recommend using the nginx approach, as nginx is very fast and powerful, though requires a little reading at first. But if you get to know it, you can use its reverse proxy feature to create powerful web caches, not only for ASP.NET, but also for all other web application like ruby, node.js and so on.